# preg_replace technicality in PHP regular expressions

Tags: expression

My current code:

```
$text = "This is my string exec001 and this is the rest of the string exec222 and here is even more execSOMEWORD a very long string!";
$text2 = preg_replace('/\bexec(\S+)/', "<html>$1</html><div>$1</div>",, $text);
echo $text2,"\n";
```

Outputs the following:

```
This is my string <html>001</html><div>001</div> and this is the rest of the string <html>222</html><div>222</div> and here is even more <html>SOMEWORD</html><div>SOMEWORD</div> a very long string!
```

My question is, how can I store multiple variables? For example: I want to replace execVARIABLE1:VARIABLE2:VARIABLE3 and store each of VARIABLE1, 2 and 3 in say $1, $2 and $3 when the string is rewritten.

Comment: expend your regex to include 3 variables: `$text2 = preg_replace('/.*?\bexec(\S+).*?\bexec(\S+).*?\bexec(\S+)/', "<html>$1</html><div>$2</div><div>$3</div>", $text);`

Comment: This doesn't work. I want to store each text separated by the colon into $1 $2 $3. Your code also deletes most of the expression.

Comment: It's just an example... I'll post an answer in a minute

Answer (score 0):

In order to save the matched groups you can use `preg_match()`:

```
$text = "This is my string exec001 and this is the rest of the string exec222 and here is even more execSOMEWORD a very long string!";
preg_match( '/.*?\bexec(\S+).*?\bexec(\S+).*?\bexec(\S+)/', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [0] => This is my string exec001 and this is the rest of the string exec222 and here is even more execSOMEWORD
    [1] => 001
    [2] => 222
    [3] => SOMEWORD
)
```

Comment: This isn't what I need. For example say we have exec:morning:afternoon and exec:evening:night in the same string. Then $1 would represent morning and evening and $2 would represent afternoon and night. I need to replace them rather than store them in an array. My existing code would store "morning:afternoon" and "evening:night" in $1, whereas I want each word seperated by the colon stored in seperate variables, ready to be used when replacing. Hopefully that is a bit clearer.

Comment: After we store the captured groups in params like I showed - we can use them with string-replace afterwards, for example: `echo str_replace("exec".$matches[1], "<html>".$matches[1]."</html><div>".$matches[1]."</div>", $text);`

Comment: This will not work because we never know how many occurences of exec:someword there will be in the string.

Comment: @user3931836 on the contrary - that's exactly why it'll work: you'll get *all* the strings of format exec:* in the result array (you can later on loop the array and use str_replace() to replace each and every match with what you want).

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't work. The code limits us the three occurences of "exec:" in the string whereas in my string the number of "exec:" occurences is unknown. I'm not referring to the variables separated with a ":" , but rather the actual OCCURENCES of "exec:".

Comment: @user3931836 Where do you see a limit to 3 parameters in the code above ? It doesn't work because you're not doing it right :) Anyways, it's late here and I'm too tired... maybe tomorrow... good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to M42, we have the correct answer as follows:

```
$text2 = preg_replace('/\bexec([^:\s]+):([^:\s]+)/', "<html>$1</html><div>$2</div>", $text);
```